# Time Machine on Big Sur stuck on "Preparing Backup" ... and no .inProgress file to delete?

Tags: time-machine, big-sur, time-capsule

Did the file structure for the Time Machine change with Big Sur? After returning from holiday and not backing up for a month, my early 2015 Macbook Pro on Big Sur 11.5.2 was stuck on "Preparing Backup." (I let it run overnight two days, it was really stuck). I've had this problem in the past and have used the advice that's everywhere on the web, delete the .inProgress file from Backups.backup... But neither that directory nor that file are in my Time Machine:

[image]

Apple's unhelpful help pages list the reasons a Mac gets stuck on "preparing backup" but offers no fix.

I can enter the Time Machine fine and see the history of backups and restore a file as normal. The Time Machine Preferences window shows a red exclamation mark and flags the fact that the last backup didn't complete because the Mac was on battery power.

How can I goose the Mac or the Time Machine to re-commence backup?